# Randomize integers in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am attempting to randomize all integers in a string. 
E.g "Transferred to account 123456789" randomized into "Transferred to account 256829876"

I already have a slow solution in PL/SQL where I am looping through each character in the string individually. If char is an asci value between 48-57 (digits 0 to 9), I randomize the digit accordingly.

In SQL I have gotten this far:

```
select regexp_replace('Transferred to account 05172262116','[0-9]',
                      floor(dbms_random.value(0, 10)))
from dual;
```

However, this does not give me the expected result as integers are replaced with a single unique value. (E.g. 'Transferred to account 555555555')
Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for via use of SQL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the numbers are always 11 digits, you can explicitly look for that:

```
select regexp_replace('Transferred to account 05172262116','[0-9]{11}', floor(dbms_random.value(10000000000, 99999999999)))
from dual;
```

Otherwise, you can replace with an integer, but the length may not be the same length as the original one:

```
select regexp_replace('Transferred to account 05172262116','[0-9]+', floor(dbms_random.value(10000000000, 99999999999)))
from dual;
```

As a note:  things like account numbers are often removed using `translate()`, but this produces a fixed string:

```
select translate('Transferred to account 05172262116', ' 0123456789', ' ##########')
from dual;
```

(And you can do the same thing with `regexp_replace()`.)

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. Unfortunately, my table column contain integers of different length, not limited to account numbers. It is important that length is maintained after randomizing integers. If I cannot achieve what I am looking for without use of complex PL/SQL operation, I opt to replace each digit with fixed digit 0 or 9. Performance is more important than realistic looking data.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be viewed as a cop-out, but I would argue that information as sensitive as an account number should not be shown in *any* form, even if the digits are randomly permuted.  So, I recommend just completely masking the account number using e.g.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('Transferred to account 05172262116', '[0-9]', '*')
FROM dual;
```

Even the above presents some security risk, because it shows the same number of `*` as there are digits in the account number.  But, it is often the case, e.g. with credit cards or account numbers at a given bank, that all account numbers have the same length anyway.

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking to display a permutation of the digits of the actual account.  Data masking with "realistic-looking" data is important for development instances.  Masking all accounts to something like "******************" makes the data much less useful for development.  For example, you cannot judge performance because what would be a very selective index in production now becomes worthless in your development instance.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Maybe, but then we shouldn't be working wth an English sentence containing an account number, right?  There should be a single column containing an account number.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is that you are doing the replace once.  This gets you one value to replace each character with.  To do this correctly you would have to loop through each character and get a new random value to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `translate()` with a single 10-digit random number:

```
select translate('Transferred to account 05172262116',
  '1234567890',
  floor(dbms_random.value(1000000000, 10000000000))) from dual;

TRANSLATE('TRANSFERREDTOACCOUNT051
----------------------------------
Transferred to account 81677787668
```

It will work with any number of digits anywhere in the string, and preserves the original length (number of digits) of the replaced value. It maps an original digit to the same (random) digit each time, at least within that string. (If you apply the same translate across multiple source rows at one, they will get different mappings as `dbms_random` is non-deterministic).

```
with t (s) as (
  select 'Transferred to account 05172262116' from dual
  union all
  select 'Transferred to account 05172262116' from dual
)
select s, translate(s,
  '1234567890',
  floor(dbms_random.value(1000000000, 10000000000))) from t;

S                                  TRANSLATE(S,'1234567890',FLOOR(DBM
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
Transferred to account 05172262116 Transferred to account 57238858225
Transferred to account 05172262116 Transferred to account 95587747554
```

Each digit in your original string is translated to the corresponding digit in the random number. For instance, the first output above came from the generated random number 6703187918. The first digit of you original string was 0; that's the 10th digit of the second argument to `translate()`; so you get the 10th digit of the (random) replacement string which is the third argument to that function - which is 8. The second digit in your string is 5, which is the 5th digit in the second argument; so you get the 5th digit in the third argument - which is 7. And so on.

---

It's arguable if this is random enough, I suppose, but the main goal is presumably to stop you reconstructing the original value from the replacement. You could potentially learn something about the shape of the original value by looking for repetitions new one; but as you could have repeated characters in the random value too that doesn't get you very far.

For instance, in the example above the replacement has a row of three consecutive 7s, so you might think the original has three consecutive digits too - but it didn't. The random value had two positions - 2nd and 7th - which both mapped to 7 in the new string, and you can't tell which of those mapping was applied. (So even if you knew the random value you couldn't get back to the original, in this case anyway - it won't always have repeated numbers, of course.)